# How can a table access value from the M side of relationship of the 1 side of its relationship?

Tags: powerbi

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-many-to-many-relationships#the-previous-workaround

[image]

[image]

[image]

A visual that displays State (from the CityData table), along with total Population and total Sales, would then appear as follows:

[image]

Since table expansion happens always to the 1 side of 1:M relation, how did the above visual column State (from city data table) be able to get the value for sales? Sales table is not reachable from the citydata table since sales is on the M side of another link (not the city data and state table link)

Comment: https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/expanded-tables-in-dax/#

Comment: Yes it says that table expands towards 1 side. So when city data table expands to also have state. But how does it also get access to sales?

Comment: Read the article carefully: "If you activate the bidirectional cross-filter on a relationship, you are not relying on table expansion. Instead, the engine pushes certain filtering conditions in the code in order to apply the filters on both sides"